# Using \def inside mathematical environment

Tags: definition

I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{witharrows}


\begin{document}
    
\def\var{x}
    
\[
    \begin{WithArrows}
        \var\var&=\def\var{y}\var\var\\
        \var
    \end{WithArrows}
\]

\end{document}
```

I wanted to change the `\var` value to *y* but it only works for the `\var` immediatly after the `\def` and on that line.

The result of the compilation is:

[image]

And I'm wondering why the `\var` on the second line is not affected by the instruction above.

Comment: What would be the reason for the redefinition?

Comment: @egreg I'm thinking about exercises where you need a change in variable (like solving limits)

Comment: So losing track of what is what? I'm not sure how this can be helpful.

Comment: @egreg it's understandable that you are not sure how it can be helpful but I am, that's good enough for me. Thank you.

Comment: @egreg I now see your point and you are correct! I made an exercise resolution and sent it to a friend in a .tex file and he had a lot of difficulties editing it because of commands I used... I still think the idea is good to send the finished product but if I plan on ever sending the .tex it would be problematic. Sorry for being harsh in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `\def` to `\gdef`, to make the definition global.  Inside the environment, each subline is its own group, so the `\def` does not carry over outside of it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{witharrows}


\begin{document}
    
\def\var{x}
    
\[
    \begin{WithArrows}
        \var\var&=\gdef\var{y}\var\var\\
        \var
    \end{WithArrows}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]